# Compare 2 dictionaries and return missing values

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-core

How would I compare these 2 dictionaries and return only the values missing?

The *GetFileListFromBlob()* function gets all file names and I'd like to know what is missing from the db.

Or is there a better way to get the missing values from these objects? Should I use different key/ value?

```
Dictionary<int, string> databaseFileList = new Dictionary<int, string>;
Dictionary<int, string> blobFileList = new Dictionary<int, string>;

int counter = 0;
foreach (string f in GetFileListFromDB())
{
    counter++;
    databaseFileList.Add(counter,  f );
}

counter = 0;
foreach (string f in GetFileListFromBlob())
{
    counter++;
    blobFileList.Add(counter, f);
}

// How to compare?
```

Thank you

Comment: Use `HashSet<string>` instead and get rid of the counter, construct the database hashset with `var databaseFileSet = new HashSet<string>(GetFileListFromDB(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`, and then just do `var missing = GetFileListFromBlob().Where(f => !databaseFileSet.Contains(f)).ToList();`.

Comment: Are you looking for values missing in first list or second list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) might be what you want (instead of a `Dictionary<K,V>`) - take this example:

```cs
var reference  = new HashSet<string> {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
var comparison = new HashSet<string> {"a",           "d", "e"};
```

When you now call `ExceptWith` on the reference set ...

```cs
reference.ExceptWith(comparison);
```

... the `reference` set will contain the elements `"b"` and `"c"` that do not exist in the `comparison` set. Note however that the extra element `"e"` is not captured (swap the sets to get `"e"` as the missing element) and that the operation modifies the reference set in-place. If that isn't wished for, the [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1) LINQ operator might be worth investigating, as was already mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @LDS For complex data types, you'd have to implement `IEquatable` and override `GetHashCode()` in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you don't need counters at first (you can add them later).

You can use `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` type to go on.

```
List<int, string> databaseFileList = new List<string>(GetFileListFromDB());
List<int, string> blobFileList = new List<string>(GetFileListFromBlob());

//some code
```

Now if you want to get all items in both lists you can simply use `Concat(...)` method to unify them and then use `Distinct()` method to remove duplicate items:

```
List<string> allItems = databaseFileList.Concat(blobFileList).Distinct();
```

Now use `Except(...)` method to compare collections:

```
var missingItems1 = allItems .Except(databaseFileList);
//or
var missingItems1 = allItems .Except(blobFileList);
//or
//some other code
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
private void CompareDictionary()
{
    var databaseFileList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var blobFileList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    databaseFileList.Add(300, "apple");
    databaseFileList.Add(500, "windows");
    databaseFileList.Add(100, "Bill");

    blobFileList.Add(100, "Bill");
    blobFileList.Add(200, "Steve");

    var result = databaseFileList.Where(d2 => !blobFileList.Any(d1 => d1.Key == d2.Key)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The dictionary's `ContainsValue` method might be a better choice compared to `Any`.